# LESS Nested Rule &

Tags: less

Due to comments I add that `.vmiddle, .vmiddle td, .vmiddle th` doesn't work in my case because I'm using bootstrap and it defines `.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td` with vertical-align: top;

which take precedence.

I want to perform this css:

```
.vmiddle,
table.vmiddle thead tr td,
table.vmiddle tfoot tr td,
table.vmiddle tbody tr td,
table.vmiddle thead tr th,
table.vmiddle tfoot tr th,
table.vmiddle tbody tr th,
table thead.vmiddle tr td,
table tbody.vmiddle tr td,
table tfoot.vmiddle tr td,
table thead.vmiddle tr th,
table tbody.vmiddle tr th,
table tfoot.vmiddle tr th,
table thead tr.vmiddle td,
table tbody tr.vmiddle td,
table tfoot tr.vmiddle td,
table thead tr.vmiddle th,
table tbody tr.vmiddle th,
table tfoot tr.vmiddle th,
table thead tr td.vmiddle,
table thead tr th.vmiddle,
table tbody tr td.vmiddle,
table tbody tr th.vmiddle,
table tfoot tr td.vmiddle,
table tfoot tr th.vmiddle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

somehow i get it to work with this rules :

```
.vmiddle {
    vertical-align:middle;
    & {
        table& {
            & thead , tfoot, tbody {
                tr, {
                    td, th {
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        thead&, tbody&, tfoot& {
            table & {
                tr {
                    td, th {
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        tr& {
            thead &, tbody &, tfoot & {
                table & {
                    td, th {
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        td&, th& {
            tr & {
                thead &, tbody &, tfoot & {
                    table & {
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but looks actually more complicated than the standard soluction :D
Is there any shorter way to do it and without defining vertical-align:middle 5 times ?

Comment: Wouldn't just `.vmiddle, .vmiddle td, .vmiddle th` be sufficient? It seems to me that every other rule is unecessary and already included in it unless you've got some other more specific selectors that would override it.

Comment: exactly, im using bootstrap which define `.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td` with `vertical-align: top;` and that takes precedence

Comment: Then I think this may be a rare case where using `!important` should be considered. Or just go with the first css version if you don't find any other solution, it seems a lot more readable than the less one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your not using the '&' selectors properly.

From [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules):

> the & combinator - it’s used when you want a nested selector to be
>   concatenated to its parent selector, instead of acting as a
>   descendant. This is especially important for pseudo-classes like
>   :hover and :focus.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> .bordered {
>   &.float {
>     float: left;
>   }
>   .top {
>     margin: 5px;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Will output
>
> ```
> .bordered.float {
>   float: left;
> }
> .bordered .top {
>   margin: 5px;
> }
> ```

But in your case it doesn't look like you even need to use it.

**Edit:**

Regarding the specificity issue (mentioned in the comments below) simply add a class on the root (table) element and the specificity problem goes away. So if we call the calss .table:

LESS:

```
.table .vmiddle
{
   vertical-align: middle;
   td, th
   {
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
}
```

Comment: I agree but because of specificity I must use all parent selectors because frameworks like bootstrap define `.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td` with `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: @Bart So define a class on the root of your table like .table and the specificity problem goes away

Comment: Amazing... unfortunatelly bootstrap uses the class table and I'm thinking about another name for the root table element but I can't figure out what would be a good name for it :D

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you should be able to shorten those long css rules. In certain situations it won't work but generally you should avoid unnecessary long selectors to get better performance and readability. An example of methodically reducing the rules:

- Any `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `th` and `td` will always be in a table, you can remove the `table` selector part.

  ```
  .vmiddle,
  .vmiddle thead tr td,
  .vmiddle tfoot tr td,
  .vmiddle tbody tr td,
  .vmiddle thead tr th,
  .vmiddle tfoot tr th,
  .vmiddle tbody tr th,
  thead.vmiddle tr td,
  tbody.vmiddle tr td,
  tfoot.vmiddle tr td,
  thead.vmiddle tr th,
  tbody.vmiddle tr th,
  tfoot.vmiddle tr th,
  thead tr.vmiddle td,
  tbody tr.vmiddle td,
  tfoot tr.vmiddle td,
  thead tr.vmiddle th,
  tbody tr.vmiddle th,
  tfoot tr.vmiddle th,
  thead tr td.vmiddle,
  thead tr th.vmiddle,
  tbody tr td.vmiddle,
  tbody tr th.vmiddle,
  tfoot tr td.vmiddle,
  tfoot tr th.vmiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```
- Any `tr`, `th` and `td` will always either be in a `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot`, you can remove those. Many rules are now identical, remove those too.

  ```
  .vmiddle,
  .vmiddle tr td,
  .vmiddle tr th,
  tr.vmiddle td,
  tr.vmiddle td,
  tr.vmiddle td,
  tr.vmiddle th,
  tr.vmiddle th,
  tr.vmiddle th,
  tr td.vmiddle,
  tr th.vmiddle,
  tr td.vmiddle,
  tr th.vmiddle,
  tr td.vmiddle,
  tr th.vmiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```
- Any `th` and `td` will always be a child of a `tr`, remove `tr`. Remove all duplicates again.

  ```
  .vmiddle,
  .vmiddle td,
  .vmiddle th,
  td.vmiddle,
  th.vmiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```
- `td.vmiddle` and `th.vmiddle` are already covered by `.vmiddle`.

  ```
  .vmiddle,
  .vmiddle td,
  .vmiddle th {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

Comment: I agree but because of specificity I must use all parent selectors because frameworks like bootstrap define `.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td` with `vertical-align: top;`